# How can submit form with array fields and process on view?

Tags: python, django

I am trying to submit form with array fields and process on Django view. Also, I want to compare the submitted form data with correct answer table data.

question.html:

```
<form method="post" class="form-inline">
        {% csrf_token %}

        {% for question in questions %}
            <h3>{{ question.title }}</h3>

            <div class="radio">
                <label class="radio-inline">
                    <input type="radio" name="ans{{ question.id }}" value="{{ question.option.0 }}">
                    {{ question.option.0 }}
                </label>
            </div>

            <div class="radio">
                <label class="radio-inline">
                    <input type="radio" name="ans{{ question.id }}" value="{{ question.option.1 }}">
                    {{ question.option.1 }}
                </label>
            </div>

            <div class="radio">
                <label class="radio-inline">
                    <input type="radio" name="ans{{ question.id }}" value="{{ question.option.2 }}">
                    {{ question.option.2 }}
                </label>
            </div>
        {% endfor %}

        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" name="ans_submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

view.py:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
  if(request.POST.get('ans_submit')):
        temp_context["submitted_answers"] = request.POST.get("ans", "") # Receive as an array?
```

Expecting to get expert advice.

Thanks

Comment: Only one option needs to be selected in the answer right?

Comment: How is the first line of your view? does it have `question_id ` as parameter?

Comment: Yes, from the MCQ based question set @arulmr

Comment: @ettanany sorry, the view do not have the question_id as a parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually what is posted to you is `ans0`, `ans1`, `...`, `ansN`.
So what you want to do is something like this:

```
answer_fields = [field for field in request.POST if field.startswith('ans')]
for field in answer_fields:
    # Do something with `field`...
    print(request.GET[field])
```

Additionally, you might want to check that the latter part is numeric, like so:

```
[field for field in request.POST
 if field.startswith('ans') and field[3:].isnumeric()]
```

Comment: Thanks. It's showing "MultiValueDictKeyError" after submitting the form!

Comment: Can you try and remove the `[` and `]` from the name(s) of the radio buttons?

Comment: Changed but seems result is same -Django Version:  1.9.6
Exception Type:  MultiValueDictKeyError
Exception Value:  

"u'ansace9e1de-b9ff-447a-b2df-3ef228e55a66'"

Comment: Ah. You have UUIDs as IDs. Then the last part will not work (where I use `str.isnumeric`).

Comment: Thanks! Actually, I didn't use the last part from if clause but receiving the error message.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129700/discussion-between-thwe-and-tobias).